# Fatal error:Class 'DrupalDefaultEntityController' not found error is showing after upgrading drupal 6.62 to 7.41

Tags: php, drupal

Fatal error:Class DrupalDefaultEntityController not found error is showing after upgrading drupal 6.62 to 7.41 ?

Comment: We have upgraded drupal v6.13 to 7.41. we are getting error after upgrading.

configuration details php version is : 5.3 appache2 mysql 5

Error: Fatal error:Class ' DrupalDefaultEntityController ' not found.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the article about "[Fixing a Broken Drupal 7 Registry](http://randyfay.com/content/fixing-broken-drupal-7-registry)". It suggests you try to use the [Registry Rebuild](https://www.drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild) module as a possible solution for your issue.

Using this module as a possible remedy is also what is suggested in [issue # 1837570](https://www.drupal.org/node/1837570).

Comment: is it possible to upgrade successfully ?

Comment: Were you able to fix the problem?